# optimal method to parse a json object in a datafile

Tags: python, json, regex

I am trying to setup a simple data file format, and I am working with these files in Python for analysis.  The format basically consists of header information, followed by the data.  For syntax and future extensibility reasons, I want to use a JSON object for the header information.  An example file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my material",
  "sample-id": null,
  "description": "some material",
  "funit": "MHz",
  "filetype": "material_data"
}
18  6.269311533 0.128658208 0.962033017 0.566268827
18.10945274 6.268810641 0.128691962 0.961950095 0.565591807
18.21890547 6.268312637 0.128725463 0.961814928 0.564998228...
```

If the data length/structure is always the same, this is not hard to parse.  However, it brought up in my mind a question about the most flexible way to parse out the JSON object, given an unknown number of lines, and an unknown number of nested curly braces, and potentially more than one JSON object in the file.

If there is only one JSON object in the file, one can use this regular expression:

```
with open(fname, 'r') as fp:
    fstring = fp.read()

json_string = re.search('{.*}', fstring, flags=re.S)
```

However, if there is more than one JSON string, and I want to grab the first one, I need to use something like this:

```
def grab_json(mystring):
    lbracket = 0
    rbracket = 0
    lbracket_pos = 0
    rbracket_pos = 0

    for i in range(len(mystring)):
        if mystring[i] == '{':
            lbracket = 1
            lbracket_pos = i
            break

    for i in range(lbracket_pos+1, len(mystring)):
        if mystring[i] == '}':
            rbracket += 1
            if rbracket == lbracket:
                rbracket_pos = i
                break
        elif mystring[i] == '{':
            lbracket += 1

    json_string = mystring[lbracket_pos : rbracket_pos + 1]
    return json_string, lbracket_pos, rbracket_pos

json_string, beg_pos, end_pos = grab_json(fstring)
```

I guess the question as always: is there a better way to do this?  Better meaning simpler code, more flexible code, more robust code, or really anything?

Comment: Use JSON for all data, one JSON structure per file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution, as Klaus suggested, is just to use JSON for the entire file.  That makes your life much simpler because than writing is just `json.dump` and reading is just `json.load`.

A second solution is to put the metadata in a separate file, which keeps reading and writing simple at the expense of multiple files for each data set.

A third solution would be, when writing the file to disk, to prepend the length of the JSON data.  So writing might look something like:

```
metadata_json = json.dumps(metadata)
myfile.write('%d\n' % len(metadata_json))
myfile.write(metadata_json)
myfile.write(data)
```

Then reading looks like:

```
with open('myfile') as fd:
  len = fd.readline()
  metadata_json = fd.read(int(len))
  metadata = json.loads(metadata)
  data = fd.read()
```

A fourth option is to adopt an existing storage format (maybe [hdf](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/)?) that already has the features you are looking for in terms of storing both data and  metadata in the same file.

Comment: Thinking about it more, keeping everything in the same JSON makes sense, although as a matter of parsing, I am still curious if there is another answer related to that.  Part of the reason I asked this question is that I wanted to leave open the possibility of easy manual file creation by copy/paste from Excel, which my company works with copiously, and having the data block after the JSON makes that easy.  Next best solution is to have:
"data": [
x, y1, y2, y3 ,y4,
x, y1, y2 , y3, y4....]
though this requires a bit of find/replace before pasting.

Answer (score 0):

I would store headers separately. It'll give you a possibility to use the same header file for multiple data files

Alternatively you may want to take a look at [Apache Parquet Format](https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/) especially if you want to process your data on distributed cluster(s) using [Spark power](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files)